# Размер экрана пользователя

Tags: gwt, javascript, java

Как получить размер экрана пользователя используя JavaScript или GWT? Размер желательно получить до загрузки остального JS кода.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ нашел.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function OnPageLoad() {
  var el = document.getElementById("my_root_element");
  if (el != null) {
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    var h = window.innerHeight;

    el.style.width = w+"px";
    el.style.height = h+"px";        
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: @ХэшКод Примите мой ответ на вопрос.

Comment: Это внутренний размер окна (где сайт отображается), а не экрана .-.

Comment: Мне помогло.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.spravkaweb.ru/javascript/reference/screen - оно?

Comment: Нет, не оно. Для моего обозревателя (Хром), что просто height, availHeight возвращается одно и тоже значение.

Comment: В гугловском хроме он возвращает размер экрана. ЧЯДНТ?
Может, у вас панель тоже сбоку?)

Comment: Проверил в Хроме alert(screen.height + " " + screen.availHeight); . Значения разные. Может, вы в полноэкранном режиме запускали?

Comment: Нет. В обычном. Панель у меня по центру ставится.

Answer (score 1):

В GWT это делается так:

> import
> com.google.gwt.user.client.Window;
>
> ...
>
> int height = Window.getClientHeight();
>
> int width = Window.getClientWidth();