# Как узнать высоту окна браузера?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.  
Вопрос такой:
       Как в JavaScript вычислить высоту открытого окна браузера (той части, где находится непосредственно web-страница). Мне надо решение *без* использования каких-либо библиотек JavaScript (напр. jQuery).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Размер экрана пользователя](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/14911/) ?

Comment: Спасибо. Там все ответы.

Comment: Это даже лучше, чем я хотел)